# ReactJS onClick not firing when in a specific div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a CRA set up and all is working fine, there is one component in particular though that onClick events on an element are not firing. Based on Tim Smith's method [here](https://www.iamtimsmith.com/blog/lets-build-a-search-bar-in-react/).

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './SearchForm.css'

class SearchForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        filtered: []
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      filtered: this.props.items
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      filtered: nextProps.items
    })
  }

  handleChange(event) {

    // Variable to hold the original version of the list
    let currentList = []

    // Variable to hold the filtered list before putting into state
    let newList = []

    // If the search bar isn't empty
    if (event.target.value !== "") {
      // Assign the original list to currentList
      currentList = this.props.items

      // Use .filter() to determine which items should be displayed
      // based on the search terms
      newList = currentList.filter(item => {

        // change current item to lowercase
        const lc = item.name.toLowerCase()

        // change search term to lowercase
        const filter = event.target.value.toLowerCase()

        // check to see if the current list item includes the search term
        // If it does, it will be added to newList. Using lowercase eliminates
        // issues with capitalization in search terms and search content
        return lc.includes(filter)
      })
    } else {

      // If the search bar is empty, set newList to original task list
      newList = this.props.items
    }

    // Set the filtered state based on what our rules added to newList
    this.setState({
      filtered: newList
    })
  }

  handleSelect(string) {
    console.log(string)
  }

  render() {
    var _this = this

    this.search_results = this.state.filtered.map(function(item, key) {
      return (
        // THESE onClicks DO NOT FIRE
        <li key={item.id} onClick={(e) => _this.handleSelect(item.object)}>
          <div className="name">{item.name}</div>
          <small>{item.type}</small>
        </li>
      )
    })

    return (
        <div className="search">
                <input type="text" className="search-form" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search by client or advisor" />
                <div className="results-container">
                    <ul className="results">
                        {this.search_results}
                    </ul>
                    // BUTTON HERE (in .results-container) DOES NOT FIRE
                    <button onClick={(e) => _this.handleSelect('hi')}>hi</button>
                </div>

                // BUTTON HERE (out of .results-container) FIRES
                <button onClick={(e) => _this.handleSelect('hi')}>hi</button>

            </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchForm
```

I have tried using just this vs. _this, binding/not binding the handleSelect function, passing and not passing event to it, passing and not passing any variables at all to it (and just having handleSelect console.log a 'firing'). I realize that the use of "this" within the map was a no go, thus the _this variable. Within that map, if I console.log(_this.handleSelect), it shows the function in the console.

Thank you in advance for taking a look!

Comment: try testing with an annoymous functions so you don't have to worry if binding is causing you the problem. Code: <button onClick={()=>{console.log("it works")}}hi</button>. If this doesn't work remove the ''results-container" and just test with a normal div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved-- this ended up being an issue where the .results-container was hidden (via display: none;) and was only shown (via display: block) when the .results-container was focused on. Due to this no onClick events were firing on the items within .results-container.

Got around it by:

```
.search .results-container {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input.search-form:focus + .results-container, .search .results-container:hover {
    height: auto;
}
```

Thank you Acy for sending me in the right direction!